# File spinner_background_material.xml does not exist (or is not a file) android xml

Tags: android, xml, ide

I get this error when try to view the xml in the editor view.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Typeface.createAssetUid(Typeface.java:219)
at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:193)
at com.accionplus.dbdplus.vistas.font.MaterialDesignIconsTextView.setTypeface(MaterialDesignIconsTextView.java:28)
at com.accionplus.dbdplus.vistas.font.MaterialDesignIconsTextView.<init>(MaterialDesignIconsTextView.java:22)
at com.accionplus.dbdplus.vistas.font.MaterialDesignIconsTextView.<init>(MaterialDesignIconsTextView.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:176)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:317)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:654)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:82)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:596)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:591)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It says "Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE" but I can't figure it out. This error doesn't let me see the icons or the elements correctly in the preview of the editor.

Comment: Do you have control over the view implementation?